# Google Chrome assigns a text field as a password field

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, angular-material

I have a basic text field but Google Chrome assigns it as a password field.

```html
<form [formGroup]="formBuilder">

  <p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Type a title" formControlName="title">
    </mat-form-field>
  </p>

  <p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </p>

  <p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Label of a detail</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text"> <!-- THE PROBLEM -->
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Description of a detail</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text">
    </mat-form-field>
  </p>

</form>
```

This is what it looks like if I click on that input field:

[image]

I have tried the same code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-niwl2q?file=src/app/app.component.html) but there it looks good and I don't see the problem there.

I am running that page on localhost:4200. How comes this field is a password field??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My problem was solved when I added IDs to the input fields.

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Label of a detail</mat-label>
  <input id="detail-label" matInput type="text">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Description of a detail</mat-label>
  <input id="detail-description" matInput type="text">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I don't know why adding an id on an input that has the same issue as described in the question fix it. Thanks ! Anyone has an idea why ?

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Not sure why it is happening, but can confirm that adding an id fixed it.